# Dependent buildpacks are not found when using "pack build"

Tags: buildpack, cloud-native

I am new to buildpacks and am trying to create buildpacks for Apache Spark.

So far, I have this:

`spark-init/buildpack.toml`:

```ini
api = "0.8"

[buildpack]
  id = "MYREGISTRY/buildpacks/spark-init"
  description = "A Cloud Native Buildpack which downloads and installs Apache Spark"
  version = "0.0.1"

[[stacks]]
  id = "io.buildpacks.stacks.bionic"

[[stacks]]
  id = "io.paketo.stacks.tiny"

[[stacks]]
  id = "*"
```

`spark-init/package.toml`:

```ini
[buildpack]
  uri = "."
```

`spark/buildpack.toml`:

```ini
api = "0.8"

[buildpack]
  id = "MYREGISTRY/buildpacks/spark"
  description = "A Cloud Native Buildpack which builds a Spark app"
  version = "0.0.1"

[[order]]
  [[order.group]]
    id = "MYREGISTRY/buildpacks/spark-init"
    version = "0.0.1"
  [[order.group]]
    id = "gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java"
    version = "9.5.0"
```

`spark/package.toml`:

```ini
[buildpack]
  uri = "."

[[dependencies]]
  uri = "../spark-init"

[[dependencies]]
  uri = "docker://MYREGISTRY/buildpacks/spark-init:0.0.1"

[[dependencies]]
  uri = "docker://gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java:9.5.0"
```

I already packaged the `spark-init` buildpack, I can run `docker pull MYREGISTRY/buildpacks/spark-init:0.0.1`.

When I now run

```bash
pack build test-spark-app --path /path/to/some/spark/app --buildpack spark
```

I get:

```
base: Pulling from paketo-buildpacks/builder
Digest: sha256:c1e38424191fb515597c542a0b2253ca29b670334afa6a2564e9df9f5a80bf60
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/builder:base
base-cnb: Pulling from paketo-buildpacks/run
Digest: sha256:f30b94d1acc0ccd74c416b4c83b59081f9f51a92a80e33793a43eb4f0afe4ceb
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/run:base-cnb
ERROR: failed to build: validating buildpacks: buildpack MYREGISTRY/buildpacks/spark-init@0.0.1 not found on the builder
```

What am I missing? Why are my buildpacks not found? I *can* explicitly state the `spark-init` buildpack at the command line but then it barks on not finding the Java one, besides, this would make this mechanism totally useless when you manually have to state all dependencies used.

Comment: Do you have a public git repo with your buildpacks handy? did you publish those buidlpacks to a registry so we can try them out?
I believe your issue is that you need to specify explicitly  all buildpacks - not just the one you want.
For example, when I'm testing a new buildpack, that is not yet part of a builder, I need to do such things: https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip/pull/174#issue-1694118753

Comment: Not 100% sure what is happening, but it thinks your buildpack is on the builder, which it isn't going to be because you're using the paketo builder which won't have your buildpack. What is `spark` supposed to be? Is it a path on disk? `pack` might not know and it might be related to the fallback behavior, https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/specify-buildpacks/#fallback-behavior. You might try `file://` if it's a local buildpack, so it's not ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I can't publish the code because it's company internal. I actually figured it out that when I give all buildpacks explicitly or make a new builder that contains them it resolves them. Plus, my version of `pack` doesn't seem to know the Docker protocol, if I state a `docker://` URI I get: `unsupported protocol docker in URI`